# ram upgrade on Dell Inspiron e1705

Tags: memory, upgrade, dell-inspiron

How can I tell if my Dell Inspiron e1705 ram can be ugraded to 2G or more?

Answer (score 2):

The Dell documentation for the Inspiron e1705 indicates the laptop supports a maximum of 2GB of RAM (here's a link to the [spec page as part of the manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins9400/en/om/specs.htm#wp1082923)).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [Dell homepage](http://www.dell.com/us/en/dfh/notebooks/inspn_e1705/pd.aspx?refid=inspn_e1705&cs=22&s=dfh) you can upgrade the Inspiron e1705 up to 2 GB RAM. Click on "Tech Specs" and scroll down a bit. In the third column you can see the memory description.